# Problem with deployment by using Netlify in first step new site from Git

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy my site(testing site) witNetlify, 
by using https://geeeva.github.io/test/ as site, and in first step create a new site on Netlify in form I use a branch to deploy - gh-pages and empty field for build command and empty field for publish directory. I got a link for the site https://hardcore-neumann-8b6a13.netlify.com from Netlify but the content is unfortunately empty, it's a blank page, and when I enter in code inspector I have js errors in console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () main.b6a753f2.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 2.6efc73d3.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () main.b6a753f2.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /test/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /test/manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /test/manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token. main.f3f5397b.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Can somebody help with this problem?